# Why doesn't HTML load CSS correctly?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I don't know why, but CSS is not loading. I tried everything in the last 30 minutes:

> My directories:

[image: Text]

> Root.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> The important part of app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')


const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')


app.set(express.static(publicPath))
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', viewsPath)
hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath)
```

> Styles.css:

```
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: href="../../public/css/styles.css" ?

Comment: I tried the relative path as well, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving both files into the same directory and then only using "styles.css" as a path?